# How to achieve big growing Python lists backed by a file and not loaded into memory at any point

Tags: python

I have a python script that needs to maintain some values as list and append to the list every n seconds for an indefinite period until the user quits the script. I want the list to be file backed to which i can append without loading the list contents into memory, the only part that will be in memory will be the value that is to be appended.

I tried [Shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) but after running some tests i found out that at some point of time i will have to have to load the existing persisted list into memory and append to it, with writeback = true, it keeps the whole file into memory and writes to file at the end only.

The script goes like this:-

```
d = shelve.open( reportDir+curDatName+ ( processName.rsplit('.', 1)[0] if processName.endswith('.exe') else processName ))
    global counter
    global startTime

    d['CPU|'+pid] = []
    d['RAM|'+pid] = []
    d['THREADS|'+pid] = []

    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    while(not quit):
        print('Took a snapshot')
        counter = counter + 1
        p = psutil.Process(int(pid))
        list = d['CPU|'+pid]
        print(list)
        list.append(p.cpu_percent(0.1)/psutil.cpu_count(0.1))
        d['CPU|'+pid] = list
        print('CPU '+ str(p.cpu_percent(0.1)/psutil.cpu_count(0.1)))
        list = d['RAM|'+pid]
        list.append(p.memory_percent())
        d['RAM|'+pid] = list
        print('RAM '+ str(p.memory_percent()))
        list = d['THREADS|'+pid]
        list.append(p.num_threads())
        d['THREADS|'+pid] = list
        print('Threads- '+ str(p.num_threads()))
        print(d['RAM|'+pid])
        i=0
        while(not quit and i < interval/chunkWait): #wait in chunks
            i = i+1
            time.sleep(chunkWait)
```

Is there any other package that can achieve the desired functionality for me?

Comment: You need a database.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a list, which is an in-memory data structure, to store data that is too big to fit conveniently in memory. You are asking for some package that will allow you to pretend that you are using a list when in fact you are dealing with a list-like interface that in actuality has a disk-based backing store. That would be convenient, and there is at least one first-class proprietary API that I know that does it, for the vendor's own database (so not generic). And no doubt someone somewhere has come up with a generic list-like interface to a database table, but that would simply be syntactic sugar. I suspect you are going to have to abandon your list approach and learn a database API. This is not a forum for such recommendations, but I think I won't get flamed or downvoted for saying that `mysql` is free and has a very good reputation.